# C # Cómo manejar los valores null en una expresión lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, null

Este es mi método, el objeto `sugetionRequest` trae 3 valores:

- `int capacityNeeded`
- `string preferredNeigborHood`
- `string [] resourcesNeeded)`

Los dos últimos pueden ser `null`, ¿cómo puedo manejar esto? Para que la consulta me devuelva un resultado en función de la capacidad si ambos son nulos, en función de la capacidad y los recursos si el vecindario es nulo o en función de la capacidad y el vecindario si los recursos son nulos, ¿todo se puede hacer en la misma consulta?

```
    public IEnumerable<IOffice> GetOfficeSuggestion(SuggestionRequest suggestionRequest)
    {
        var resources = suggestionRequest.ResourcesNeeded;

        var neigborhoodLocation = locations
                    .Where(x => x.Neighborhood == suggestionRequest.PreferedNeigborHood);

        return offices
            .Where(o => resources.All(r => o.AvailableResources.Contains(r)) 
            && o.MaxCapacity >= suggestionRequest.CapacityNeeded 
            && neigborhoodLocation.Any(l => o.LocationName == l.Name))
            .OrderBy(o => o.AvailableResources.Except(resources).Count())
            .Select(o => new OfficeDto
            {
                Name = o.Name,
                LocationName = o.LocationName,
                MaxCapacity = o.MaxCapacity,
                AvailableResources = o.AvailableResources
            });
    }
```

Estos datos son enviados a través de este `Test XUnit` en el cual efectúan la carga de las oficinas con las cuales debo comparar y sugerir la mas cercana a los requisitos pedidos. Los mismos datos que son enviados al método del test ya tienen cual `location` y `office` debería devolver el método

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(18, "Palermo", null, "Centro 2", "1")]
    [InlineData(6, "Centro", new[] { "wi-fi", "tv" }, "Centro 2", "3")]
    [InlineData(2, null, null, "Centro 1", "4")]
    [InlineData(2, null, new[] { "proyector", "catering" }, "Centro 2", "1")]
    [InlineData(30, null, null, null, null)]
    public void ShouldGiveOfficeSuggestions(int capacityNeeded, string preferedNeigborHood, string[] resourcesNeeded, string expectedLocation, string expectedOffice)
    {
        OfficeRental.AddLocation(new LocationSpecs("Centro 1", "Centro"));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Centro 1", "1", 12, new[] { "wi-fi", "proyector", "cafe" }));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Centro 1", "2", 8, new[] { "wi-fi", "tv", "cafe" }));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Centro 1", "3", 8, new[] { "wi-fi" }));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Centro 1", "4", 4, new[] { "tv" }));

        OfficeRental.AddLocation(new LocationSpecs("Centro 2", "Centro"));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Centro 2", "1", 20, new[] { "wi-fi", "proyector", "cafe", "catering" }));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Centro 2", "2", 6, new[] { "wi-fi", "tv", "cafe" }));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Centro 2", "3", 6, new[] { "wi-fi", "tv" }));

        OfficeRental.AddLocation(new LocationSpecs("Palermo", "Palermo"));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Palermo", "1", 10, new[] { "wi-fi", "tv" }));
        OfficeRental.AddOffice(new OfficeSpecs("Palermo", "2", 8, new[] { "wi-fi", "tv" }));

        var suggestions = OfficeRental.GetOfficeSuggestion(new SuggestionRequest(capacityNeeded, preferedNeigborHood, resourcesNeeded));
        Assert.Equal(expectedLocation, suggestions.FirstOrDefault()?.LocationName);
        Assert.Equal(expectedOffice, suggestions.FirstOrDefault()?.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Y q es lo q quieres hacer?

Comment: Yo tengo oficinas, cargadas previamente, y necesito devolver una sugerencia de oficina segun los requisitos (suggestionRequest) entonces en la consulta estoy filtrando los datos que llegan y funciona perfecto, pero si los datos que menciono son null entonces en la consulta solo devuelve null y no me sugiere nada cuando deberia sugerirme basado en la capacidad necesaria, por eso mi pregunta es, en la consulta como deberia manejar si esos datos son null

Comment: Y son son null cual seria el resultado esperado?

Comment: Perdon, no especifique eso, que la consulta me devuelva un resultado en función de la capacidad si ambos son nulos, en función de la capacidad y los recursos si el vecindario es nulo o en función de la capacidad y el vecindario si los recursos son nulos.

Comment: La verdad no entiendo lo que deberia devolver, pero si te sirve de algo podes controlar los null con el operador "?" o con en metodo IsNullOrEmpty() para los arrays

Comment: Debería devolver la oficina que cumple con los requisitos pedidos, ya tengo cargada en una lista esas oficinas, y debe devolver la mas próxima a las necesidades, todo esto es para ejecutar el test, editare y agregare detalles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola si se puede hacer pruebe este ejemplo

```
 return offices
             .Where(o =>
             o.MaxCapacity >= suggestionRequest.CapacityNeeded
             && (resources == null ? true : resources.All(r => o.AvailableResources.Contains(r)))
             && (neigborhoodLocation == null ? true : neigborhoodLocation.Any(l => o.LocationName == l.Name)))
             .OrderBy(o => o.AvailableResources.Except(resources).Count())
             .Select(o => new OfficeDto
             {
                 Name = o.Name,
                 LocationName = o.LocationName,
                 MaxCapacity = o.MaxCapacity,
                 AvailableResources = o.AvailableResources
             });
```

en la primera condición valido la capacidad, después pregunto si resources es nulo varifico contra *true* porque esa condición se ignora, y lo mismo con los vecindarios, Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Rene! me funciono perfecto solo tuve que agregar una condición mas en la parte del vecindario  teniendo en cuenta el primer dato que me pasan en el test. Pero me sirvió a la perfección, realmente nunca había realizado una consulta tan avanzada entonces no sabia bien que hacer. Nuevamente gracias!!

Comment: Por nada Daniel me alegro que haya resuelto su problema